# Медленная загрузка страницы из-за большого количества изображений

Tags: php

На страницу загружается в цикле около 850 изображений, из-за этого довольно долго грузится страница. Подскажите, может можно как-то сжать их или другие доступные способы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Оптимизировать изображения (коль метка php например с помощью GD)
2. Использовать отложенную загрузку изображений например с помощью https://plugins.jquery.com/lazyload/ (условно говоря загружать по 10-20 картинок, а остальное подгружать если пользователь прокручивает страницу вниз)

Answer (score 2):

3 подхода к увеличению скорости загрузки страницы с изображениями:

1. Оптимизировать изображения для использования в сети при помощи https://libjpeg-turbo.org/, http://optipng.sourceforge.net/ или любых аналогичных утилит. Наибольший эффект даст при больших размерах изображений.
2. Объединить изображения в спрайты и показывать часть спрайта вместо изображения. За счёт этого значительно сокращается кол-во запросов к серверу. Наибольший эффект даст при загрузке очень большого кол-ва маленьких изображений.
3. Разместить изображения на стороннем CDN сервисе (выбор сервисов очень большой). Необходимо выбирать сервис, который ближе к основной части пользователей сайта. Минусы: большинство сервисов взимают абонентскую плату за хранение ваших файлов, прирост скорости может оказаться незначительным (необходимо тестирование).